# express-keepalive not.. staying alive

Tags: express, gruntjs

My `grunt` tasks look like:

```
grunt.registerTask "default", [
    "clean:dist"
    # "useminPrepare"
    "copy:dist"
    "ngmin"
    # "jshint"
    # "coffee_jshint"
    "usemin"
    "express"
    "express-keepalive"
]
```

It executes the tasks, including `Running "express-keepalive" task`, but then doesn't keep express running or even started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use "grunt-contrib-watch" as a separate task -- that makes grunt keep running, which makes the server keep running.

I am not sure about this -- I just hit the same problem myself, and this is how I got it to keep running.  If there is a better answer, I would also like to know.